# Chaves estrangeiras em java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou com um pouco de dificuldade para implementar as chaves estrangeiras no meu exemplo. Alguém pode me ajudar a montar a classe DAO?

CidadeDAO.java

```
public class CidadeDAO {
    private final Connection connection;

    public CidadeDAO() {
        try {
            this.connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void adiciona(Cidade cidade){
        String sql= "insert into cidade (nome, cep, id_estado) values (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        try{
            stmt= connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, cidade.getNome());
            stmt.setString(2, cidade.getCep());
            //  como faço o setString do estado?
            stmt.execute();
            stmt.close();  
        }catch(SQLException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

EstadoDAO.java

```
public class EstadoDAO {
private final Connection connection;

    public EstadoDAO() {
        try {
            this.connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void adiciona(Estado estado){
        String sql= "insert into estado (nome, sigla, regiao) values (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        try{
            stmt= connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, estado.getNome());
            stmt.setString(2, estado.getSigla());
            stmt.setString(3, estado.getRegiao());
            stmt.execute();
            stmt.close();  
        }catch(SQLException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Cidade.java

```
public class Cidade {
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String cep;
    private Estado estado;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }
    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }
    public Estado getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }
    public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }       
}
```

Estado.java

```
public class Estado {
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String sigla;
    private String regiao;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }
    public void setSigla(String sigla) {
        this.sigla = sigla;
    }
    public String getRegiao() {
        return regiao;
    }
    public void setRegiao(String regiao) {
        this.regiao = regiao;
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual a exceção/erro que ocorre mesmo?

Comment: Ainda não implementei a classe de teste da cidade. Primeiro preciso saber como setar as chaves estrangeirar para poder dar o insert. Poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: No método `adiciona()` na classe CidadeDAO, a cidade passada como argumento já deve ter o estado setado nela, daí é só pegar o id do estado fazendo `cidade.getEstado().getId()`. Isso caso esteja armazenando o id no BD, se for o nome daí seria `cidade.getEstado().getNome()`, mas eu recomendo que seja o id, pois ele deve estar setado como único no BD, então não é para ocorrer inconsistências.

Comment: E na classe main, o que eu devo colocar? Seria algo do tipo "cidade.setEstado(id_existente);"?

Comment: Desculpe a indiscrição da pergunta, mas o seu objetivo neste caso é didático (aprender)? Ou pretende criar uma aplicação de uso próprio ou comercial? Se for a segunda opção, já pensou em utilizar JPA ou mesmo um framework para o desenvolvimento? Pois muitas dessas questões básicas já estariam resolvidas e vc poderia ir direto ao "negócio".

Comment: Estou tentando aprender mesmo. Ver como a coisa funciona, sabe? Vou deixar os frameworks para mais adiante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O *DAO* de **Cidade** pode, naturalmente, obter o *id* do **Estado** lendo a propriedade *cidade.getEstado().getId()*.

Você pode setar no estado o *id* que foi gerado para ele na hora em que ele foi inserido pelo seu respectivo *DAO*.

Para obter o *id* gerado por uma inserção (lógico que estamos falando de uma coluna auto-incremento) você deve informar um parâmetro adicional na hora de criar o *prepared statement*, assim:

```java
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Repare que utilizei *executeUpdate*, que é o método que expressa uma alteração no banco de dados.

Depois de executar o comando, leia o *result set* produzido pelo comando acima, assim:

```java
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
rs.next();
int idGerado = rs.getInt(1);
```

<sub>Uma boa prática é verificar se de fato foi obtido um result set e se de fato há linhas neste result set. Se você for adicionar estas validações você também precisa decidir o que fazer em caso negativo (o que pode ocorrer por exemplo se o campo *id* não for auto-incremento). Pode ser que seja válido lançar uma exceção que facilite a identificação do problema em tempo de execução.</sub>

Agora você pode setar no estado o *id* que foi gerado para ele durante sua inserção. O código completo para adicionar estados fica mais ou menos assim:

```java
public void adiciona(Estado estado){
    String sql= "insert into estado (nome, sigla, regiao) values (?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    try{
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setString(1, estado.getNome());
        stmt.setString(2, estado.getSigla());
        stmt.setString(3, estado.getRegiao());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        
        // abaixo você obtém o id gerado para a coluna auto-incremento do MySql
        // e seta este id no objeto Estado que está sendo adicionado.
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        rs.next();
        int idGerado = rs.getInt(1);
        estado.setId(idGerado);
        
        stmt.close();  
    }catch(SQLException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

O método "main" que cria estes dois objetos fica mais ou menos assim:

```java
Estado estado = new Estado();
// ... estado.setXXX(...) - seta todas as propriedades do estado, exceto seu id.
estadoDAO.adiciona(estado);

Cidade cidade = new Cidade();
cidade.setEstado(estado);
// ... cidade.setXXX(...) - seta as demais propriedades da cidade.
cidadeDAO.adiciona(cidade);
```

E o método *CidadeDAO.adiciona* recebe uma linha para setar o *id* do estado:

```java
stmt.setInt(3, cidade.getEstado().getId());
```

E está pronto.

## Algumas boas práticas:

- Você pode validar as propriedades obrigatórias das entidades antes de inserir de modo a ter erros mais descritivos do que exceções de banco de dados ou *NullPointerException*.
- Procure manter as classes das entidades e seus respectivos *DAO*s no mesmo package, um package exclusivo, e então defina como *protected* os métodos *set* que não são do interesse do consumidor, como por exemplo o *setId*, que será setado automaticamente pelo *DAO*.

Comment: Caffé, muito obrigado por sua explicação! Agora está funcionando perfeitamente.